# DNN module, version 3 manifest - can a "license" tag be added?

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke

I'm trying to figure out how to add a license tag to my DNN module manifest.  It looks simple in version 5, but I'm trying to do it in version 3 (that's the version my company's using).

I haven't been able to find anything on Google.

Is this possible in version 3?  If so, what should this tag look like, and where should it be placed?  Here's a pared down skeleton version of my manifest:

```
<dotnetnuke version="3.0" type="Module">
 <folders>
  <folder>
   <name>ModuleName</name>
   <friendlyname>ModuleName</friendlyname>
   <foldername>ModuleName</foldername>
   <modulename>DNN_ModuleName</modulename>
   <description>Blah blah</description>
   <version>01.00.00</version>
   <businesscontrollerclass>DotNetNuke.Modules.ModuleName.ModuleName</businesscontrollerclass>
   <modules>
    <module>
     <friendlyname>ModuleName</friendlyname>
     <cachetime>0</cachetime>
     <controls>
      <control>
       ...
      </control>
     </controls>
    </module>
   </modules>
   <files>
    <file>
     ...
    </file>         
   </files>
  </folder>
 </folders>
</dotnetnuke>
```

So far I've tried placing it after the dotnetnuke tag, after the folder tag, and after the module tag.

Thanks in advance, folks  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DotNetNuke Version 3.x does not support including license text in the module installation manifest.  You can however include a license.txt file in your package that includes any licensing information you require.

Answer (score 0):

As [@Trillium said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8884645/2688), that's not supported.  Version 5 was the first to support licenses (see the [Manifests](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Wiki/Page/Manifests.aspx) page on the DotNetNuke wiki for the syntax).